# Page Administration & Open Graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm an Admin for this page

[http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.westberks.gov.uk%2Findex.aspx%3Farticleid%3D23789](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.westberks.gov.uk/index.aspx?articleid=23789)

and I've also specified that my App can administer it too. I've Liked this page so I thought I should be able to access the admin screen for the page but I can't seem to. Any ideas on how I access the admin screen for this page in FB, so I can manually publish updates?

Additionally, when I try to update page programmatically I get the message

*(OAuthException) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action*

but the page has my App listed here

http://graph.facebook.com/10150303466842688

Comment: That looks fine to me, when logged in as either of the uids specified, or as an admin of that app you should see the page listed in your list of pages and be able to see the administration interface right on your web page. The update problem is separate, you need to grant your app the manage_pages permission to write to a page the user admins

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Neither user sees the page in their list of pages and when clicking on the Liked page in their timeline I'm taken to the web page itself rather than the Facebook Page.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem. Have you thought about raising a bug?

Answer (score 1):

**This was definitely a bug** rather than a programming or setup issue. **The bug has been marked fixed by Facebook** as of 1/18/2012 and everything now works as it is supposed to! Bug report:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/308356579205492?browse=search_4f0f1475c470b2076799347

Until this recent fix, there was a problem where OpenGraph pages did NOT allow the admins of those pages to retrieve page access tokens for them. Which means they were locked out of posting "as the page" and apparently also locked out of the Admin area for their own pages as well.

I know that this is fixed for me now with this bugfix, and hopefully it will also be fixed for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ask for `manage_pages`, `read_stream` and `publish_stream`.  Once your admin accepts those permissions, the app can call `me/accounts` on the Graph (play here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).  In there will be a list of all the pages they admin.  In each listing will be a unique access token.  This is called the page access token.  Using that token you should be able to read and write to the `me/feed` for that page.